# Probability: Rotating circular board

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Let there be a circular board that is divided into $2^k$ sectors (similar to a dartboard). Each sector can be red with probability $p$ and green with probability $1- p$. If we rotate the board, when it comes to rest, I am interested in an event that a red sector covers the 6 o'clock direction.

Now let $X$ denote the reward that one gets when the above event occurs. The random variable $X$ takes a value according to the following rule: $X = 1/t$, when $1 \leq t\leq 2^k$ sectors are red and one of them covers the 6 o'clock direction, i.e., the reward of $1$ is shared among those red sectors. I am interested in the probability mass function of $X$. When none of the sectors that are red covers the 6 o'clock direction, the reward is $0$, i.e., $X = 0$.

**My attempt**: There are $2^k + 1$ combinations depending on how many of the $2^k$ sectors are red, e.g., $0$, $1$, $2$, $\dotsc$, $2^k$. Let $p_n$ denote the probability that $n$ sectors are red before rotating the board. Then we have
$$p_n = {2^k \choose n}p^{n}(1-p)^{2^k-n}, \,\,\,\, 1 \leq n \leq 2^k.$$
Now, for the case when there are $1 \leq t \leq 2^k$ sectors are red, the probability that a red sector covers the 6 o'clock direction is $$q_t = \frac{t}{2^k}.$$

So, one has
$$
X =
\begin{cases}
1, \quad \text{w.p.}~~ p_1q_1 \\
\frac{1}{2}, \quad \text{w.p.}~~ p_2q_2\\
\vdots \\
\frac{1}{2^k}, \quad \text{w.p.}~~ p_{2^k}q_{2^k} \\
0, \quad \text{w.p.}~~(1-p)^{2^k}.
\end{cases}
$$

Then the probability that a red sector covers the 6 o'clock direction is
$$P_{c} = \sum_{n = 1}^{2^k} p_n q_n.$$
The probability that no red sector covers the 6 o'clock direction is
$$P_{n,c} = (1-p)^{2^k}.$$

Then the following equation should hold:
$$P_{c} + P_{n,c} = 1.$$
But it does not hold true. To check this, let us consider the case of $k = 1$. In this case,

$$P_{c} = \frac{1}{2}2p(1-p) + \frac{2}{2}p^2$$
and
$$P_{n,c} = (1-p)^2.$$
Here, $P_c + P_{n,c} \neq 1$.

What am I missing here?

Comment: +1 to the query.  Debit is that you didn't proofread before.  For me, that is much more than offset by excellent presentation and work shown, for a complex math problem.

Comment: @Oscar, did you mean to say The event that a *green* (not red) sector covers the required direction?  If so, your comment is quite correct. But all that means is that $P_{n,c}\gt(1-p)^{2^k}$, since there are plenty of ways in which the required direction can be covered by green even if some of the sectors are red.

Comment: Ah, I just realized that. I think the error is in the calculation of $P_{n,c}$. I am considering only one event that leads to not covering the required direction; there are other ways also to not cover the direction.

Comment: You have to assume the colors of the sectors have independent probability in order to come up with these answers. Interestingly, the expected value of $X$ is insensitive to that assumption. You can skip all of these calculations when evaluating $E(X).$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where your attempt goes awry is in equating the probability, $P_{n,c}$, that no red sector covers the 6 o'clock position with $(1-p)^{2^k}$. The latter is the probability that there are no red sectors at all. But it's entirely possible to have a mix of red and green sectors with the 6 o'clock position covered by green. So $P_{n,c}$ lies somewhere *between* $(1-p)^{2^k}$ and $1-p^{2^k}$ (since $p^{2^k}$ is the probability that all sectors are red).

In fact, the probability $P_c$ and $P_{n,c}$ are simply $p$ and $1-p$ respectively. That's because the 6 o'clock position is necessarily covered by *some* sector, and whichever sector that is will be red with probability $p$ and green with probability $1-p$.

Comment: Sorry for the ill-posed problem. I have improved it.

Comment: @Oscar, your original problem was not ill-posed. It may just not have been exactly what you actually wanted to ask. I've added a note to my answer to indicate it no longer quite applies.

Comment: I've revised my answer to address the OP's essential question, which concerns the error in their attempt.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't read your calculation to look for an error.

The probability that a random position on the wheel is red is just $p$, the probability that each sector is red.

**Edit** in response to the edited question, that introduces the reward for red.

The reward information is independent of the error.
The argument still relies on a calculation of

> the probability that a red sector covers the 6 o'clock direction

that relies on the sum over the possible numbers of red sections. But that probability is still just $p$. So I suspect an error somewhere in that calculation.

Comment: Sorry for the ill-posed problem. I have improved it.

Comment: @Oscar See my edit.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Summing over relevant events of one or more red sectors covering the direction, the answer is $p$. The mistake is in the calculation of the complementary event, i.e., in the calculation of $P_{n,c}$. Thanks.